How to change model opacity with animation?
I want to change the opacity of a 3D object with animation. Since RealityKit is highly integrated with SwiftUI on visionOS, I tried this method:
let model = ModelEntity()

withAnimation(.easeInOut) {
    model.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init(opacity: 0.25)
}

However, it didn't work.

If your scene contains only one 3D object, you can add an opacity modifier to the entire RealityView, and it will work properly:
RealityView { content, attachments in
    content.add(model.setupContentEntity())
} update: { content, attachments in
    // Update logic if needed
}
.opacity(0.25)
.animation(.easeInOut)


Changing model's opacity using animation
If you want to programmatically change the opacity of each individual model (not of the entire view) in a RealityKit scene using animation, I suggest you use the following code, showing model A fading out twice as fast as model B:

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView: View {
    let modelA = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.4))
    let modelB = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateSphere(radius: 0.4))
    
    init() {
        modelA.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init()
        modelB.components[OpacityComponent.self] = .init()
    }
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { rvc in
            modelA.position = [-0.5, 1.0,-4.0]
            modelB.position = [+0.5, 1.0,-4.0]
            rvc.add(modelA)
            rvc.add(modelB)
            
            let _ = rvc.subscribe(to: SceneEvents.Update.self) { _ in
                if modelA.components[OpacityComponent.self]!.opacity > 0 {
                    modelA.components[OpacityComponent.self]?.opacity -= 0.002
                }
                if modelB.components[OpacityComponent.self]!.opacity > 0 {
                    modelB.components[OpacityComponent.self]?.opacity -= 0.001
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Thank you, but this method seems quite low-level—so much so that I even have to handle the animation curves myself.If Apple could introduce a more high-level API at WWDC2024, I would be very happy.

Hi @闪电狮, This is definitely a high level API, not a low level one. This approach doesn't seem logical or convenient, but at the moment this is what works for each separate entity in runtime.
